# How do you create a wallet with MultiBit?

Tags: wallet, multibit

I just downloaded MultiBit for Windows and I am trying to create a wallet. When I click that, nothing happens.  It just says "connecting" on the bottom left status bar. No wallets are seen.

Well, I did that (clicked "create wallet") and nothing happened.  The wallet file shows up in the correct spot on my desktop (the .wallet file I mean...) but nothing show up in the wallet column on the app itself.

Perhaps my firewall is blocking something?  on the bottom left it does not say "connected".

[image: app with no wallet]

Comment: Hey Doug, to me it is not clear what element you are trying to interact with when you "clicked that". Perhaps you could edit your question to clarify that part. If you feel that any of the changes I made don't match your intent, please feel free to revert or improve to your liking.

Answer (score 2):

To create a wallet in MultiBit:

1. Open MultiBit.
2. Click on "New Wallet"
   [image: Click on New Wallet.]
3. Enter a proper name for your wallet.
   [image: Create new wallet dialog box]
4. Wallah! A wallet!
   [image: Wallet successfully made!]

It sounds to me like you're having connection troubles, though. Are you behind a firewall, proxy, or anything that could interfere with your connection? Consider trying a new internet connection.

Here is the MultiBit Help page: https://multibit.org/help.html